# What's the difference between completed actions in the past and single completed actions in the past?

Tags: past-tense

What is the difference between completed actions and **single** completed actions ?
We often use the past simple tense for single completed events and past tenses , and we use the past continuous for temporary or interrupted actions .
So why don't we just say ** completed actions in the past ** rather than ** single ** completed actions in the past ?

Comment: Please give sentences as examples of these issues, what actual sentences you want to say.

Comment: The possibility of repeated actions in the past (iterative) all being completed also exists. Atelic single occurrences (eg 'sneeze') are termed semelfactive. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_aspect), which mentions the usual disagreements over terminology.

Comment: "Habitual actions" is a term commonly found in ESL/EFL books, and contrasts with single actions. "I went to work every day" vs "I went to the moon". The question is still too vague to answer exactly.